# I'm unable to access variables in template from preprocess function

Tags: 8, theming

I am using a preprocess function to get data from specific content types. I am able to print the data in the pre-process function but unable to view the same in the twig file.

This is the code I am using.

```
    function themename_preprocess_node__custom_content_type_name(&$variables) {
      $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
      // Get all products node IDs.
      $nids = $query->condition('type', 'content_type_products')->execute();
      // Load all product nodes.
      $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
      // Pass them to node--custom-content-type-name.html.twig.
      $variables['products'] = $nodes;
     //echo "<pre>";
     //print_r($variables['products']); exit;
    }
```

`print_r($variables['products'])` shows the content of `$variables['products']`, but the *node--custom-content-type-name.html.twig* file doesn't print anything for `{{products}}`.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply [EntityViewBuilderInterface::viewMultiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3AviewMultiple/8.9.x) before you can render the nodes in a twig template:

```
$variables['products'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('node')
  ->viewMultiple($nodes);
```

Twig:

```
{{ products }}
```

You can add a view mode to viewMultiple() as second argument, for example `teaser`.

Comment: When I try the above code, it is displaying the view(HTML), but here I need variables/properties of each product. like products.field_image, products.field_text so I can use them in my already designed twig

Comment: Then use a custom view mode for products and add a second template node--content-type-products--custom-view-mode.html.twig.